# store more than 10 MB offline data on Edge Mobile 15

Tags: microsoft-edge, indexeddb

I wrote a HTML5 web app (kind-of enterprise PWA) that needs to store a substantial amount of data offline (my users are aware of this).

The web app works fine in all major browsers (including Desktop, Android and iOS), however I'm experiencing problems on phones like the Lumia 640 (Edge 15 browser on Windows 10 Mobile).

It's hard to tell what the exact problem is, due to the lack of debugging capabilities of that browser. The app works fine when emulating a Lumia 650 in Edge Desktop, though.

I *guess* the problem is that I'm exceeding the "hard" storage limits described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/storage/indexeddb), since I usually store about 25 mb of JSON data and that phone has 8 GB of storage AFAIK (meaning that I hit the 10 MB limit).

Is there a way to allow a single domain to store such a large amount of data in Edge Mobile? The page linked above mentions that those *"limits are removed for UWP apps using JavaScript"* - I don't really know what that means.

Or is there an alternative way for a web application to store very large JSON objects in Edge Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm running into the same boundaries, though for me the quota limit seems more like 5MB. For instance running the Browser Storage Abuser app at https://demo.agektmr.com/storage/ I can store 1 5MB file, 9 500KB files, etc and then things start failing.

My device has 8GB storage, so maybe it's storing things in UTF16 which explains why the size appears half of what they document.

What's strange is I've tried the same on an emulator instance with a 10GB partition and I see the same limits. From that table it seems like I should be able to store twice as much.